# Scaling down the height of a rectangle to fit in a window in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, height, rectangles

I'm currently working on a project which relies on the representation of file sizes through rectangles. What I have been stuck on for quite a while however, was scaling of the height to a size that could fit inside of my Stage. This is a crucial part of the project as it allows the user to visually compare the sizes of the files they are viewing from any directory on their machine. 
EDIT: I tried adding an image but I haven't got enough reputation yet :(.
http://tinypic.com/r/2e56pol/8

Comment: You can define a scaling factor by knowing the maximum height of your rectangles and the height of your window (maxHeight/viewHeight), you can then multiple the current height of your rectangles by this factor to get a uniform scaling. You could also render the rectangles to an image and then scale the Mage as a whole. But the idea remains the same...

Comment: so I have to find the largest height of all rectangles ?

Comment: Another idea would be to normalise the heights, so that the heightist rectangle would be a factor of 1 and the smallest 0. This would then allow you to render the rectangles without caring about having to always calculate the scale (as the normalised values are already scaled)

Comment: How would that be calculated ?

Comment: You can use the file sizes. But either way, you simply loop over the list of values and use Math.max to determine which is the largest, you then re-iterate over the list and calculate the scale/normalised value...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just bind the height of the rectangle to the scene's using:

```
rectangle.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

A complete example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DemoTabPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20,20,200,200);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(rectangle), 100, 100);
        rectangle.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the code. Can you please explain it ? I mean the width binding especially.

Comment: Binding helps you to bind the height of your rectangle with respect to your scene/stage's height. In my example the factor is 100% i.e. no matter how big or small your stage is, the rectangle will fill the height completely.

Comment: Do I bind it before or after I have made changes to fill , rotation angle ... etc ?

Comment: I have added your code , but it seems that it hides all of the rectangles. Also, I'm looking to have a height between the rectangles that is different for each so that it can be compared by the user , just like I have explained above.

Comment: I've made more or less of an alteration to my code using MadProgrammer's first suggestion. Thank you Mad.

Comment: @MichalManugiewicz If you have multiple rectangles and you add the binding to each one of them, each one will spread throughout the scene trying to fill it up. In case you have multiple rectangles, try using a scaling factor on the binding.